# Как изменить значение label онлайн

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть 10 покупок в приложении для приобретения некоторых функций моего приложения и еще одна покупка, чтобы купить все функции моего приложения. Также у меня есть label со скидкой рядом с покупкой всех функций, чтобы показать преимущества этого предложения пользователю.
Например, мне нужно изменить цены и скидку. Я могу быстро изменить цены в аккаунте разработчика. Но чтобы изменить скидку мне нужно загрузить новую версию моего приложения в App Store потому что значение скидки прописано вручную в приложении. И ради скидки заливать новою сборку - это очень долгий процесс. Поэтому я пытаюсь найти более простой способ изменить скидку на моем label.

Например, я могу скачать с сервера файл `.txt` с размером скидки. Тогда я могу изменить значение в этом `.txt` файле в любое время и пользователь всегда будет получать актуальное значение. Но я не уверен, что это лучший способ. В конце концов, мне всегда нужно спрашивать у пользователя разрешение на скачивание файла. Может быть, лучший способ показать значение скидки из .html чтобы ничего не качать? Или еще как-то? Но как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и через свой сервер. Но судя по вашим вопросам, знаний пока не хватит.

Советую использовать готовые хранилища данных. Например, [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-ios) . Firebase данную функцию предоставляет бесплатно.

Есть такой вариант: Поднимаете на сервере базу данных, там храните все товары со всеми полями(цена, название и т.д.). Отдаете приложению по запросу все товары. Например, в формате json.

Comment: С этим проблем нет. Есть сервер. И файлы с него без проблем загружаю). Просто вопрос в лучшем варианте.

Comment: @User. Дополнил ответ. Передавать файлы не лучшее решение